# Possible issue with multer? Error: Router.use() requires callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, multer, angular-fullstack

Building a site with yeoman angular-fullstack works great locally, but when I deploy and use the dist/release version it gives me this fun error on my server.

```
Error: Router.use() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]
at Function.proto.use (/home/bitnami/htdocs/dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:327:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bitnami/htdocs/dist/server/api/save/index.js:10:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at module.exports (/home/bitnami/htdocs/dist/server/routes.js:13:25)
```

It seams that it's failing on this line

```
router.use(multer({ dest: './public/uploads/'}));
```

Though it works locally completely fine? Has me a bit stumped. 
Wonder if its related to multer? I have the node module installed.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recent versions of `multer` changed the API. If you look at the [examples](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), you will see you now have to do something like:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: './public/uploads/'});

// ...

router.use(upload.single('foofield'));
```

Or `upload.array()` or `upload.fields()`.

Comment: Hah, yeah.... I half wondered if that's what was up. Should of checked the docs before posting :derp: Thanks pointing that out!